# SQL server Data Tuning Advisor error

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL server 2008 DTA for the first time and I get the following warning message

> 55% consumed workload has syntax errors

And because of this I don't see any recommendations for tuning my DB.

Please help.

Comment: How did you create this workload?

Comment: I followed steps given here http://blogs.technet.com/b/sql_server_isv/archive/2011/04/01/creating-a-workload-by-using-a-trace-log.aspx

Comment: we get them as well :-( our DBA says it's normal, but I don't understand how that can be..

Answer (score 1):

It could be normal, if the workload submitted is not valid anymore.

For example, suppose you had a table (also temp tables) and referenced this table in the queries you recorded in workload. If you drop the table or the temp table does not exist anymore, the workload still references it and DTA will throw a syntax error.

Check the workload, it should be possible to open it in management studio, so you can verify it.

Pay attention to temp tables, especially if created with `SELECT INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`, it seems this is not parsed correctly by DTA.